# MySQL LIMIT and GROUP BY with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to GROUP BY one tables column, but LIMIT by another in one query. Something like:

```
SELECT items.*, subitems.*
FROM items
LEFT OUTER JOIN subitems ON subitems.subitem_itemId = items.item_id
GROUP BY subitem.subitem_id
LIMIT 10
```

... but where the LIMIT 10 applies to the amount of item records, not actual rows. so i get 10 items, but unlimited subitems, therefore potentially more than 10 actual rows (or not if there are equal or less children than parents).

I can then loop through these in php and set up the parent/child relationships. Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use a sub-query for this:

```
SELECT items.*,subitems.*
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM items
    LIMIT 10
) AS items
LEFT OUTER JOIN subitems ON subitems.subitem_itemId = items.item_id
GROUP BY subitem.subitem_id;
```

Comment: Yeah, older versions of MySQL don't support sub-queries--or many other things that many of us take for granted these days.  I believe MySQL 5 and later supports sub-queries, but I'm not really sure--I haven't used MySQL regularly since the 3.23 days. And I don't know of an alternate way to accomplish the same thing in older versions of MySQL, or other DB engines that don't support sub-queries, except to do two queries in the client.

Comment: I can use subqueries. Thanks for the answer :)